Context variable always comes up as undefined in my custom hook (ReactJS)
I am writing a custom hook as shown below to perform api calls throughout my application:
import { useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { appInsights } from '../appInsights';
import MyContext from "../../MyContext";

// Custom hook to perform API call
export default function useApiCall() {
    const uuid = useContext(MyContext);
    const idToken = useContext(MyContext);`your text`
    const PerformApiCall = async (path, method, headers) => {
        try {
            const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_APIM_URL;
            console.log('PerformApiCall', uuid, path, method)
            //Set default header values
            headers = {
                ...headers,
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_OCP_APIM_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${idToken}`,
                "CorrelationId": uuid
            };

            appInsights.trackEvent({ name: 'API Call Started', properties: { path, method } });

            const response = await axios({
                method,
                url: `${baseUrl}${path}`,
                headers,
            });
            appInsights.trackEvent({
                name: 'Response Received',
                properties: { path, method, statusCode: response.status }
            });
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            appInsights.trackException({
                exception: error,
                stackTrace: error.stack,
                properties: { path, method }
            });
            throw error;
        }
    }

    return PerformApiCall;
}

I am using this hook in one of the components which is wrapped inside the context provider. The nesting of the components is as follows:
<MyContext.Provider value = {idToken, uuid}> 
    <Router>
        <Route url={someroue}>
            <MyCallingComponent>
        </Route>
    </Router>
</MyContext.Provider>

The issue I am facing is, the value of the context variables idToken and uuid are correct when I access them inside MyCallingComponent,but are always undefined in my custom hook useApiCall. I do not understand how hooks work completely and this is the first custom hook I am writing.

This looks like a typo: value = {idToken, uuid}. Do you want value = {{idToken, uuid}}. Also please show how you access context in the component too. It should be the similar. Also please only call hook inside the sub tree of the Provider
